# Android ListView Math equation Interface

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to program an activity where a user has an input interface to enter three different values(an equation) and a listView to display them.
My current app uses an arraylist in which(with arraylist.add) a new value gets added. With adapter.notifydatasetchanged() the standart adapter is updated and the list view changed.

But my programme needs to have 2 additional features:

1. getter Functions on the listView in order to later use the entered data
2. the possibility to delete an entry in the list by for example pressing it

One approach of mine would that there should be a function that's the opposite of Arraylist.add() in order to delete an element from the data shown in the list view(I wouldn't need getter Functions from the ListView) But in order to delete a certain element I would still need to know which element was clicked...

Although this should not be such a special problem I haven't found a good solution for this specific problem so any kind of experience is appreciated:D...

Thank you very much

Comment: How much have you gotten done so far? Ask about the specific parts where things aren't working for you. That way you will get better focused answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add do this with 2 approach:

1.Delete at once's - Means **add a Delete button in each item of list** and by click of that button you can delete that data item from ArrayList and then notify Adapter to refresh `ListView`

Also you can add deleted Item in separate `ArrayList` for your record which items was deleted so you can use this for your further business operations .

2.Delete Bulk data- For this **add CheckBox in each item of list** and by click of that button you can add that data item in separate ArrayList for selected items for deletions. And When you want delete add some delete button on header or bottom of `ListView` you can delete selected Data Items from ArrayList of Initial Data list and notify `Adapter` to refresh `ListView`.